# How to link ffmpeg libs to my C program

Tags: ffmpeg, c, shared-library

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu. I just installed ffmpeg via terminal (sudo apt-get install ffmpeg). I found a [tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/) on in it with C programming. The tutorial doesn't show how to link the libs as `libavcodec/avcodec.h`, `libavformat/avformat.h`, `ffmpeg/swscale.h` to my C project.

I don't know how to link those libs. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Those are "include files", not "libraries". `https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=avcodec.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=cosmic&arch=any` says that file is in the `libavcodec-dev` package. Install this package.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
gcc -o test test.c -Wall -lavformat -lavcodec -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lm
```